# PHP MySQL Updating table row not actually updating, no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table where the user has the option to edit each row, which updates the row in the database. I'm not getting any errors with this code, it's returning "Updated record successfully" but nothing is actually getting updated in the database.

If anyone could identify the issue here I would greatly appreciate it.

table.php:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Flight Table</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modify_records.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Aircraft</th>
                                <th>Nature of flight</th>
                                <th>Authorised By</th>
                                <th>Duration</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <?php 

                        include 'config.php';
                        $conn= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
                        if ($conn->connect_error) { 
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_flights;"; 
                        $result = $conn->query($sql); 

                        ?>

                        <tbody>
                            <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <?php echo "<td align='center'><a href='edit_form.php?flight_id=" . $row['flight_id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>"; ?>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['flight_id']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['flight_date']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['aircraft_id']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['flight_nature']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['auth_by']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['auth_duration']; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

edit_form.php:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Edit</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modify_records.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['flight_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['flight_id'])) {
    // get the 'id' variable from the URL
    $flight_id = $_GET['flight_id'];

    include 'config.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM tbl_flights WHERE flight_id = $flight_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row    = $result->fetch_assoc();
}

?>

    <form action="action.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="flight_id" id="flight_id" value="<?php echo $row['flight_id']; ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="flight_date">Date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="flight_date" id="flight_date" value="<?php echo $row['flight_date']; ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="aircraft_id">Aircraft:</label>
            <input type="text" name="aircraft_id" id="aircraft_id" value="<?php echo $row['aircraft_id']; ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="flight_nature">Nature of Flight:</label>
            <input type="text" name="flight_nature" id="flight_nature" value="<?php echo $row['flight_nature']; ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="auth_by">Auth By:</label>
            <input type="text" name="auth_by" id="auth_by" value="<?php echo $row['auth_by']; ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="auth_duration">Auth Duration:</label>
            <input type="text" name="auth_duration" id="auth_duration" value="<?php echo $row['auth_duration']; ?>">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

action.php:

```
<?php

// database connection
include 'pdo_config.php';
try {
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// post data
$flight_id = $_POST['flight_id'];
$flight_date = $_POST['flight_date'];
$aircraft_id = $_POST['aircraft_id'];
$flight_nature = $_POST['flight_nature'];
$auth_by = $_POST['auth_by'];
$auth_duration = $_POST['auth_duration'];

// prepare statement and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_flights 
                        SET (flight_date = :flight_date, aircraft_id = :aircraft_id, flight_nature = :flight_nature, auth_by = :auth_by, auth_duration = :auth_duration)
                        WHERE flight_id = :flight_id");

$stmt->bindParam(':flight_id', $flight_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':flight_date', $flight_date);
$stmt->bindParam(':aircraft_id', $aircraft_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':flight_nature', $flight_nature);
$stmt->bindParam(':auth_by', $auth_by);
$stmt->bindParam(':auth_duration', $auth_duration);

// execute statement
$stmt->execute();

// success or error message
echo "Updated record successfully.";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Comment: That's not a valid UPDATE SQL statement. Please see the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) for the proper syntax.

Comment: To the best of my recollection, the UPDATE syntax should `UPDATE <tablename> SET <column> = <newvalue>,<column> = <newvalue>,... WHERE <your conditions>;`

Comment: Any reason you are mixing mysqli and PDO? Note that you have an sql injection problem in the mysqli section: `$_GET['flight_id']`

Comment: @ jeroen To be honest it's just me being careless, this was rushed and isn't the final code, I'll make it consistently PDO once it is.
What should I use instead of `$_GET`?

Comment: I corrected the UPDATE statement but it is still not updating anything?

Comment: Why are you using mysqli_ in one piece of code then using PDO syntax in another?

Comment: @ Fred -ii- Please read my response to jeroen.

Comment: ah yes I see; my bad. Well, all I can see is that you're placing the POST arrays below your binds and that could have adverse effects. You say you're not getting errors and I don't think you are checking for them. Visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and see what comes of it. Look at the HTML source in all your files also, you may see something there too (or not) and probable errors. Then come back and tell us what they are, if any.

Comment: You said also that you changed your UPDATE syntax. You should update your question with the code/syntax you're using now in order for people to see what that is. Otherwise, we don't know what you're using now.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Okay, thank you, I'll have a look at these issues. Edit: I did update the question with the code :)

Comment: @sinesine - People aren't getting properly pinged with the space between the @ and their name. There shouldn't be a space. I'm only reloading comments to see if I was mentioned.

Comment: `UPDATE tbl_flights 
                        SET (flight_date` - remove the `(` from that, That's what the error was about earlier and its related `)` for it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Sorry, didn't know this. I moved the POST arrays to above the binds, which didn't make a difference. I have a feeling it's still an issue with the SQL because I'm running that through a syntax checker and it's returning an error. I just can't see it? Edit: just saw your comment, I'll change it now.

Comment: Don't use a syntax checker, use the syntax I gave you to use in those 2 links I included up there. Syntax checkers are for syntax not error checking.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yep, works after I removed the brackets. Thanks so much!

Comment: @sinesine You're welcome. I posted an answer below if you wish to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UPDATE syntax is incorrect. There shouldn't be `()` brackets for `SET`:

```
UPDATE tbl_flights 

SET (flight_date = :flight_date,
aircraft_id = :aircraft_id, 
flight_nature = :flight_nature, 
auth_by = :auth_by, 
auth_duration = :auth_duration)

WHERE flight_id = :flight_id
```

Change it to the following:

```
UPDATE tbl_flights 

SET flight_date = :flight_date,
aircraft_id = :aircraft_id, 
flight_nature = :flight_nature, 
auth_by = :auth_by, 
auth_duration = :auth_duration

WHERE flight_id = :flight_id
```

As per the manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Example from the manual:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

As you can see, there are no `()` following `SET`.